# Cannot Disable User Programmatically With user_cancel()

Tags: 7, forms, users

I want to disable user using `user_cancel` method.

```
//A function that disables a user.
function myid_admin_disable_user(){
    try{    
        $edit = array(
            'user_cancel_notify' => true,
        );

        $method = 'user_cancel_block';  
        //5 is the user id of the account I want to disable.
        user_cancel($edit, 5, $method);     
        echo true;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo false;
    }
}
```

After running the function above, I can still use the account which is supposed to be disabled. Why? Whats wrong in my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the docs in [`user_cancel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_cancel/7.x):

> Since the user cancellation process needs to be run in a batch, either
>   Form API will invoke it, or batch_process() needs to be invoked after
>   calling this function and should define the path to redirect to.

You need to invoke the batch API in order to trigger the result.

```
// Set the notify and cancel type options.    
user_cancel(array(
  'user_cancel_notify' => TRUE,
  'user_cancel_method' => 'user_cancel_delete',
), 5, 'user_cancel_delete');

// Invoke the Batch API, disable drupal_goto(), and execute.
$batch = &batch_get();
$batch['progressive'] = FALSE;
batch_process();
```

Comment: Thank u but copying your last three lines of code to my code, does'nt do any changes. The 'batch' thing is new to me. I was currently reading about it. :)

Comment: Check your `$edit` array, the form that invokes this function supplies more values than just the notify checkbox.

Comment: That is really the thing I'm confused of. I dont know what shall I put on my $edit variable. The function 'myid_admin_disable_user' is an invoked by ajax process. See my edited post above :)

Comment: Updated, see [`user_multiple_cancel_confirm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_multiple_cancel_confirm/7.x) and its submit handler for more detail how this function evokes it.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my wrong grammar in my comments. I could not edit it anymore. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the method you want to use would block the user account, you can simply use the following code, to achieve what you want.

```php
if ($account = user_load(5)) {
  _user_mail_notify('status_blocked', $account);
  user_save($account, array('status' => 0));
}
```

If you prefer not calling `_user_mail_notify()`, as a module should not depend on a function whose name starts with an underscore (which is a way to mark the function as private), you can use the following code.

```php
if ($account = user_load(5)) {
  $notify = variable_get('user_mail_status_blocked_notify', TRUE);
  if ($notify) {
    $params['account'] = $account;
    drupal_mail('user', 'status_blocked', $account->mail, user_preferred_language($account), $params);
  }
  user_save($account, array('status' => 0));
}
```

`user_cancel()` is thought to be called in form submission handlers; plus, since you don't need to delete more accounts, you don't even need the batch API, for this task.

If you want to make the code even more complete, you could change it as follows.

```php
$edit = array('status' => 0);
if ($account = user_load(5)) {
  module_invoke_all('user_cancel', $edit, $account, 'user_cancel_block');
  $notify = variable_get('user_mail_status_blocked_notify', TRUE);
  if ($notify) {
    $params['account'] = $account;
    drupal_mail('user', 'status_blocked', $account->mail, user_preferred_language($account), $params);
  }
  user_save($account, $edit);
}
```

In this way, you notify other modules when a user account is blocked.